# $n\log (n) − n + 1 \le \log (n!) \le (n + 1) \log (n + 1) − n$ prove using integral

Tags: calculus, inequality

Can someone help me to prove this:

$$n\log (n) − n + 1 \le \log (n!) \le (n + 1) \log (n + 1) − n$$

using integrals?
Thank you,

**Edit**:
i tried using that, but i don't understand why

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log k\ge \int_1^{n}\log xdx $$

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please [edit] your question to include context: What have you tried? You'll find that people are more helpful when you give an indication of effort as well as where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a sketch

[image]

to see that

$$\int_2^{n+1}f(x-1)dx \le \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)\le \int_1^{n+1}f(x)dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\log(n!)=\log(n)+\log(n-1)+\cdots +\log(2) +\log(1)$$

$$\int \log(x) \, dx = x \log(x)-x +C$$

Comment: One more hint: upper sum and lower sum.